# Getting the watch_later as playlist in youtube api

Tags: c#, youtube-api

How do you do it? I simply can't figure it out :P

Here's how i get the standard playlists

```
Feed<Playlist> feed = mainRequest.Get<Playlist>(new Uri("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/playlists"));
Playlist playlist = feed.Entries.ElementAt<Playlist>(0);
```

But using the same method on getting the watch_later playlist like so

```
Feed<Playlist> feed = mainRequest.Get<Playlist>(new Uri("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/watch_later"));
```

returns the videos in the watch_later playlist... i've tried pretty much everything i could come up with and nothing works. 
So how to do it?

I need the playlist since i'm trying to add videos to it.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to find the playlist id, you can use v3 of the data api you can use the [Channels List](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) method.

Once you authenticate with oAuth, the playlist can be found in items.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.watchLater

I don't know much C#, but the url itself would be:

> [https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&id={CHANNEL_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&id=%7BCHANNEL_ID%7D&key=%7BYOUR_API_KEY%7D)

You can then use the [Playlists Insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/insert) method to add videos.

Comment: Yes you can do it with the YouTube Data API v3, and you can download the client library for c# from here: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/APIs#YouTube_Data_API